# Javafx NumberBinding rounding

Tags: javafx, binding, rounding

I'm working on my first JavaFX Application and I'm having troubles with a NumberBinding. I have this NumberBinding :

```
NumberBinding cellSize = Bindings.min(scene.widthProperty().subtract(150).divide(nbC.getValue()), scene.heightProperty().subtract(150).divide(nbR.getValue()));
```

Then I put panes having `widthProperty()` and `heightProperty()` bound to this `cellSize` to my `GridPane gPane`.

And the thing I want to is have a label have the same width and height as the `GridPane`, so that I put both in a StackPane and so the label is over the `GridPane` totally covering it.

I've tried to bind the label `prefWidthProperty()` and `prefHeightProperty()` to the width and height properties of the `gPane` but it doesn't work, since the real width and height of it doesn't seem to be the number of columns and rows multiplied by cellSize.

So the code I'm using right now is this one :

```
winLabel = new Label("Bravo vous avez gagné ! :)");
winLabel.prefWidthProperty().bind(cellSize.multiply(nbC.getValue()));
winLabel.prefHeightProperty().bind(cellSize.multiply(nbR.getValue()));
```

It works well, except that the label is a little bit smaller than my panes and sometimes the size of the panes just jumps a few pixels at once, in which case the label size corresponds to the panes size.
I supposed it was due to cellSize being rounded up (so the jump in size would be when we get closer to the next rouding value).

I've tried to fix it for 2 hours using `DoubleBinding` and trying everything but I don't seem to be getting anywhere. Can you help me please ?

Here's an mvce :

```
public class Mvce extends Application {

    private Scene scene;
    // will be the root of our scene
    private AnchorPane anchor;

    private GridPane gPane;
    private Label winLabel;

    // this stackPane will contain the grid and the winLabel
    private StackPane stack;

    // number of columns and rows, from which we calculate the binding cellSize
    private IntegerProperty nbC;
    private IntegerProperty nbR;
    private NumberBinding cellSize;

    private static final int WINDOW_SIZE=720;

    public void addWinLabel(){
        DoubleProperty fontSize = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        fontSize.bind(cellSize.multiply(nbC.getValue()).divide(15));

        winLabel = new Label("Congratulations, you won ! :)");
        winLabel.prefWidthProperty().bind(cellSize.multiply(nbC.getValue()));
        winLabel.prefHeightProperty().bind(cellSize.multiply(nbR.getValue()));

        winLabel.setTextFill(Color.web("#3099AA"));
        winLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        winLabel.styleProperty().bind(Bindings.concat("-fx-font-size: ", fontSize.asString(), ";",
                                                      "-fx-background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.85);"));

        anchor.getChildren().add(winLabel);
        anchor.setTopAnchor(winLabel, 75.0);
        anchor.setLeftAnchor(winLabel, 75.0);
    }

    public void createPanes(){
        anchor.getChildren().remove(stack);
        stack = new StackPane();
        gPane = new GridPane();
        cellSize = Bindings.min(scene.widthProperty().subtract(150).divide(nbC.getValue()), scene.heightProperty().subtract(150).divide(nbR.getValue()));

        for(int c=0; c<nbC.getValue(); c++){            
            for(int r=0; r<nbR.getValue(); r++){
                if(c==0){
                    RowConstraints row = new RowConstraints();
                    row.setPercentHeight(100/nbR.getValue());
                    gPane.getRowConstraints().add(row);
                }

                Pane pane = new StackPane();

                pane.minWidthProperty().bind(cellSize);
                pane.minHeightProperty().bind(cellSize);
                pane.maxWidthProperty().bind(cellSize);
                pane.maxHeightProperty().bind(cellSize);

                pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF");
                gPane.add(pane,c,r);
            }
        }

        gPane.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        stack.getChildren().addAll(gPane);
        anchor.getChildren().add(stack);
        anchor.setTopAnchor(stack, 75.0);
        anchor.setLeftAnchor(stack, 75.0);

        addWinLabel();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(720.0);
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(720.0);

        // main panes
        anchor = new AnchorPane();
        scene = new Scene(anchor, WINDOW_SIZE, WINDOW_SIZE, Color.LIGHTBLUE);

        nbC = new SimpleIntegerProperty(7);
        nbR = new SimpleIntegerProperty(7);

        createPanes();

        primaryStage.setTitle("mvce");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should edit your post and add a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will help you to find the solution or at least help us to answer you.

Comment: You're right, here it is :)

Comment: Do you know if I can up my post ? I'd really like an answer within the next 2 hours since I will send the project to a teacher tonight. Even though it's okay if I don't fix this bug, I'd like to have a cleaner project.

Comment: Do not think it is possible to up it. I had a look on it, and you're right, it seems the rounded cellSize is the problem. But I do not understand why you set `NumberBinding cellSize = Bindings.min(scene.widthProperty().subtract(150).divide(nbC.getValue()), scene.heightProperty().subtract(150).divide(nbR.getValue()));`. What was your project constraints ?

Comment: I just wanted the grid to have a width and height inferior to the scene so that it would be fully displayed without having to scroll. Hence the min (I don't want a window with width=150 pixels but height=1000 pixels to distort my grid). The `.substract(150)` part is to leave space for some buttons and a label which I didn't include in the code.

Comment: Too bad you did not precise this earlier. Anothers layouts could have been used (avoiding setting some hard-coded value), and could have solved this issue.

Comment: Can you please tell me which layout you're talking about ? I can still change this probably.

Comment: I will use one of `GridPane` or `BorderPane` layouts.

Comment: I did use a `GridPane`, although I found necessary to put panes of fixed size inside of the grid, so that empty cells would still show up (otherwise when I had a full row or full column empty they would not be displayed..

Comment: Yes you did, but I was talking about the root, not the `GridPane` you used. Another last question, do the cells should be square even if the user resizes the Stage ?

Comment: Oh yes you're right, I could have used a GridPane with 3 rows. But I'm not sure it would have been easier for my label would it?

Comment: And yes my cells have to be squares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. You have to remove the `RowConstraints` you add and bind the `Label` with his parent, the `StackPane`. Here is your mcve I modified.

```
public class Mvce extends Application {

   private Scene scene;

   // will be the root of our scene
   private AnchorPane anchor;

   private GridPane gPane;

   private Label winLabel;

   // this stackPane will contain the grid and the winLabel
   private StackPane stack;

   // number of columns and rows, from which we calculate the binding cellSize
   private IntegerProperty nbC;

   private IntegerProperty nbR;

   private NumberBinding cellSize;

   private static final int WINDOW_SIZE = 720;

   public void addWinLabel() {
      DoubleProperty fontSize = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
      fontSize.bind(cellSize.multiply(nbC.getValue()).divide(15));

      winLabel = new Label("Congratulations, you won ! :)");
      winLabel.prefWidthProperty().bind(stack.widthProperty());
      winLabel.prefHeightProperty().bind(stack.heightProperty());

      winLabel.setTextFill(Color.web("#3099AA"));
      winLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

      winLabel.styleProperty().bind(Bindings.concat("-fx-font-size: ", fontSize.asString(), ";",
            "-fx-background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.85);"));

      anchor.getChildren().add(winLabel);
      AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(winLabel, 75.0);
      AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(winLabel, 75.0);
   }

   public void createPanes() {
      anchor.getChildren().remove(stack);
      stack = new StackPane();
      gPane = new GridPane();
      cellSize = Bindings.min(scene.widthProperty().subtract(150).divide(nbC.getValue()),
            scene.heightProperty().subtract(150).divide(nbR.getValue()));

      for(int c = 0; c < nbC.getValue(); c++) {
         for(int r = 0; r < nbR.getValue(); r++) {
            // Comment these lines, as you set the size thanks to panes you add.
            // if(c == 0) {
            // RowConstraints row = new RowConstraints();
            // row.setPercentHeight(100 / nbR.getValue());
            // gPane.getRowConstraints().add(row);
            // }

            Pane pane = new StackPane();

            // Weird to me to bind min and max width and height, prefer constant value and prefHeight / prefWidth binding with the cellSize
            pane.minWidthProperty().bind(cellSize);
            pane.minHeightProperty().bind(cellSize);
            pane.maxWidthProperty().bind(cellSize);
            pane.maxHeightProperty().bind(cellSize);

            pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF");
            gPane.add(pane, c, r);
         }
      }

      gPane.setGridLinesVisible(true);
      stack.getChildren().addAll(gPane);
      anchor.getChildren().add(stack);
      AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(stack, 75.0);
      AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(stack, 75.0);
   }

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
      primaryStage.setMinWidth(720.0);
      primaryStage.setMinHeight(720.0);

      // main panes
      anchor = new AnchorPane();
      scene = new Scene(anchor, WINDOW_SIZE, WINDOW_SIZE, Color.LIGHTBLUE);

      nbC = new SimpleIntegerProperty(7);
      nbR = new SimpleIntegerProperty(7);

      createPanes();
      addWinLabel();

      primaryStage.setTitle("mvce");
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);

      primaryStage.show();
   }

   /**
    * @param args
    *           the command line arguments
    */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
   }
}
```

Some remark :

`AnchorPane#setTopAnchor(...)` (and others) are class methods (not instance ones).

As said in comments, I don't think your layout choices are the best one, but it is kind of opinion based.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works !!
I have a last problem with my view, I'll create another post if you want to check it out, it appears when I draw over the grid.

Comment: Oh and I switched to min and max width and height because I had a glitch with prefHeight/prefWidth, sometimes it would stop to be squares.